# React useState hook - component is rendered twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wonder why my component `SearchResults` is rendered twice.

In `MainPage` component I want to pass `offers` to child component `SearchResults`:

```
const mainPage = () => {

    const [offers, setOffers] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        onInitOffers();
    }, [])

    const onInitOffers = () => {
        axios.get('/offers')
            .then(response => {
                setOffers(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }


    const searchResults = (
        <SearchResults
            searchedOffers={offers}
        />
    );

    return (
        <Aux>
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <div className={classes.contentSection}>
                    {searchResults}
                </div>
            </div>
        </Aux>
    )
}

export default mainPage;
```

Why the component `SearchResults` is rendered twice? How to correctly pass `offers` to child component using hooks?

In my child component SearchResults I have to add if condition to avoid error map is not a function:

```
const searchResults = props => {


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("RENDER");
        console.log(props.searchedOffers) --> null for the first time
    }, [props.searchedOffers]);

    let offers = null;
    if (props.searchedOffers !== null) { --> props.searchedOffers is not null after the second render
        offers = props.searchedOffers.map(offer => {
            return (
                <Grid key={offer.id}>
                    <SearchResult key={offer.id} offer={offer}/>
                </Grid>
            )
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's rendered twice because, when the element mounts, you set `offers` to `null`. If you want to make sure you only render the `SearchResults` component when `offers` isn't `null`, you can do something like:

```
return (
  <Aux>
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.contentSection}>
        {offers && <SearchResult searchedOffers={offers} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  </Aux>
)
```

If you want to be super sure `offers` is an array, you can do something like `{Array.isArray(offers) && <SearchResult searchedOffers={offers} />}`.

Often when doing something async like this, you might elect to actually use a ternary operator to show a loading indicator while the fetch is happening:

```
return (
  <Aux>
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.contentSection}>
        {offers ? <SearchResult searchedOffers={offers} /> : "Loading..."}
      </div>
    </div>
  </Aux>
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick! It works! Good aproach, I didn't come up with the idea of doing that